# Formatting a dictionary in table format

Tags: python, dictionary, ordereddictionary

I need to show my dictionary in table format:

```
res = OrderedDict([('Release', '3.7.3'), ('REFDB', ['1234', '4567', '4567']), ('URL', ['http://www.test.com', 'http://www.foo.com', 'http://www.bar.com'])])
```

I am able to print the values in list format with this code

```
if res:
    for key, val in res.items():
        print (key, '-''\n', val)
else:
    print ('Version not found')
```

My expected format is -

```
Release  REFDB     SVN
3.7.3    12345     http://google.com   
         232323    http://www.yahoo.com
         4343454   http://www.test.com
         5454554   http://www.bar.com
```

Comment: You're going to have to `split` those strings into lists of strings, then use `itertools.zip_longest` to yield tuples.  Use `''` as the fill value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way to do it with [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) and [`zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest):

```
from collections import OrderedDict
from itertools import zip_longest

d = OrderedDict([('Release', '3.7.3'), ('REFDB', ['1234', '4567', '4567']), ('URL', ['http://www.test.com', 'http://www.foo.com', 'http://www.bar.com'])])

f = lambda x: x if isinstance(x, list) else [x]

for tup in zip(*d.items()):
    for a, b, c in zip_longest(*map(f, tup), fillvalue=''):
        print('{:15}{:15}{:15}'.format(a, b, c))
```

---

```
Release        REFDB          URL            
3.7.3          1234           http://www.test.com
               4567           http://www.foo.com
               4567           http://www.bar.com
```

You can change the intercolumn spacing in the string formatting if you wish to have or more less spacing.

Comment: I am getting the dictionary in a different format (updated in original question). The code fails for the current format.

Comment: @vpd Updating your question after receiving a working answer is not fair. Editing the dataset in my answer to match your new question even makes it worse. In any case, I updated the answer to match your new requirements. Next time, you should leave a comment on the answer stating your new requirement if it's not very different from the first. Otherwise, you may consider asking the question in a new post.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/) library to transform the dictionary into a data-frame.

```
from collections import OrderedDict
import pandas as pd

d = OrderedDict([('Release', '3.7.3'), ('REFDB', '12345 \n 232323 \n 4343454 \n 5454554'), ('URL', 'http://google.com \n http://www.yahoo.com \n http://www.test.com \n http://www.bar.com')])

for key in d.keys():
    d[key] =  d[key].split('\n')

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index').transpose()
```

The output will be:

```
  Release      REFDB                     URL
0   3.7.3     12345       http://google.com 
1    None    232323    http://www.yahoo.com 
2    None   4343454     http://www.test.com 
3    None    5454554      http://www.bar.com
```